# jQuery Popup/Popout

Tags: jquery, css

I have 11 images in a row and I want a popout to come out of them if the mouse hovers on one of them. So each 11 images has a different popout. I already have some code to do this, but it will only work on the first image.

Code:
**index.html**

```
<span title="Milestones" class="tl-icon">
<span class="tl-msg">
<span class="tl-msg-inside">
<div class="slice1">
        <a id="slice1">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice2">
        <a id="slice2">Slice 2</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">------</em>
</div>
<div class="slice3">
        <a id="slice3">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice4">
        <a id="slice4">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice5">
        <a id="slice5">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice6">
        <a id="slice6">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice7">
        <a id="slice7">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice8">
        <a id="slice8">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice9">
        <a id="slice9">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">---</em>
</div>
<div class="slice10">
        <a id="slice10">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">----</em>
</div>
<div class="slice11">
        <a id="slice11">RSS Feed</a>
        <em style="top: -70px; display: none;">-----</em>
</div>
</span>
```

**style.css** (Here the same code has been copied 11 times, one for each of the popouts/images)

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }

.slice1 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice1 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 700px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice2 em {
    font-size: 47px;
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
    display: none;
}.

slice3 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 220px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice3 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 220px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice4 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice4 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 70px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice5 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice5 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice6 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 380px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice6 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 380px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice7 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 170px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice7 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 170px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice8 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice8 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice9 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice9 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 110px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

slice10 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 330px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice10 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 330px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

slice11 {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
}

div.slice11 em {
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
    width: 110px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: -0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}.

#rss-icon {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.dvq.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/jquery-popup-bubble/images/icon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice1 {
    width: 700px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/yta2) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice2 {
    width: 130px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/wexm) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice3 {
    width: 220px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/imthi) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice4 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/wqxnj) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice5 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/njqxz) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice6 {
    width: 380px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/mwi2y) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice7 {
    width: 170px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/zlzgm) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice8 {
    width: 30px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/djjn) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice9 {
    width: 210px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/mmdq) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice10 {
    width: 330px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/kodc4) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#slice11 {
    width: 110px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(http://www.kttns.org/hyz) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

**tooltop.js** (The code that makes the popout popout, again one for each of the popouts/images)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice1 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice2 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice3 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice4 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice5 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice6 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice7 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice8 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice9 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice10 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slice11 a").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});
```

Why does the popout only appear for the first image?

Comment: just a comment you can probably limit your js code greatly by wrapping all your slide divs into a slide container div and adding something like the code below instead of repeating the same code for each slide id

$("#containerdiv div").each(arr, function() {
    $("this").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("em").stop(true, true).animate({opacity: "show", top: "-60"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-70"}, "fast");
    });

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been doing a couple of test with these. While I didn't get the timeline structure right (probably because I'm missing the CSS for the context in which the timeline is displayed), I got the popups to show adding this CSS declaration:

```
div {position: relative;}
```

otherwise, the `position: absolute` declaration of the `em`s takes the whole page (or the closest enclosing relatively positioned element) as reference, and thus rendering the popups offscreen (because of the -60 vertical position).

Comment: That works. Thank you very much. One other thing is there a way to center it, so it is at the center of the image?

Comment: Do you mean, center the popup?
If that is the case, perhaps you need to consider then setting the coordinates relative to the document again. To obtain the coordinates you need to use, call `offset()` on a jQuery wrapper of div, and to the `left` value, substract half the width of the popup image, and add half the width of the div (you can get it calling `width()` on it, as a jQuery wrapper of the object. `offset()` is calculated relative to the top left corner of the document.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, I've changed the pop up to another image which is slightly larger and it overlaps the timeline. How do I fix that and why did this not happen with the other image?

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If it is overlapping in the vertical direction, you need to increase the offset: where it says -60 and -70, use a greater number. Greater in absolute value, I mean.

Comment: Actually, you need to do it in the javascript as well, specially the -60 which is the end position. The -150 is just the origin point of the animation